# Постоянно соединение с сайтом

Tags: java, url

Допустим есть некий сайт, с которого я скачиваю много картинок. Пример сайта:

```
https://site.com/111.png
https://site.com/222.png
https://site.com/333.png
```

Скачиваю я их так:

```
ImageIO.read(new URL(link))
```

Проблема в том, что я скачиваю очень много и часто, что не есть хорошо для производительности. Возможно ли открыть соединение к сайту и скачивать картинки только по их "id"? Чтобы каждый раз не создавать соединение. Либо открыть одно соединение и скачать через него много картинок разом.

Comment: Зависит от сайта, обычно - можно. Но для вашей задачи это практически не уменьшит трафик.

Comment: Да дело особо не в трафике, а в том, что на создание соединения тратится время.

Comment: `HttpUrlConnection` умеет [persistent connection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-keepalive.html) с 1.6 точно, поэтому все должно само работать. Другое дело, что он не поддерживает HTTP/2, поэтому стоит посмотреть на Apache HttpClient, OkHttp или java.net.http.HttpClient (с jdk 11).

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете установить соединение с web-сервером и попытаться запросить сразу несколько файлов, только если сервер поддерживает [HTTP pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining):

```
Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("site.com"), 80);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

pw.println("GET /1.jpg HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: site.com");
pw.println("Connection: keep-alive");
pw.println();
pw.println("GET /2.jpg HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: site.com");
pw.println();
pw.flush();

String t;
while ((t = br.readLine()) != null) System.out.println(t);

br.close();
pw.close();
s.close();
```

Если сервер не поддерживает keep-alive, я бы вынес закачку картинок в разные потоки, это ускорит время работы вашей программы.